# Execute a jsfl script on a FLA file from command line (in Windows)

Tags: flash, cmd, jsfl, adobe-animate

This question has already been asked and had been closed that's why I ask it again in the hope that it will help someone.

How to execute a jsfl script on a file.fla using a command line with the terminal of Windows (CMD). Not within `Adobe Animate`.

I have already tried with `flash.exe JSFL_file` but it has not worked for me. (It has opened the adobe flash player window with a blank page but did nothing).

([Link to the closed question] ([Execute a jsfl script on a FLA file using a command line in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950948/execute-a-jsfl-script-on-a-fla-file-using-a-command-line-in-windows)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Mofi and the link he gave ([How to run a jsfl script from the command line?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2647578)), the problem was resolved. Indeed, I had to type this type of command on the terminal of Windows (CMD):

`Path\To\Animate.exe   file.fla   Path\To\file.jsfl`

instead of

`Path\To\AdobeFlashPlayer.exe   Path\To\file.jsfl`